# Apache: how to call "static int lua_handler(request_rec *r)" function from the proxy

Tags: c, apache, lua, proxy, hook

**Hello everybody,**

I m trying to call the Apache lua module from "mod_proxy_wstunnel.c" in order to exploit the mod_lua functions.

Herein my code [mod_proxy_wstunnel.c]:

```
...
#include "#include "../../mod_lua.h"
...
...
static void ap_proxy_http_register_hook(apr_pool_t *p)
{   
    proxy_hook_scheme_handler(proxy_wstunnel_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
    proxy_hook_canon_handler(proxy_wstunnel_canon, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
    ap_hook_handler(lua_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE); // added line
}
```

I added the  ap_hook_handler(lua_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE); line in order to call the mod_lua handler.

- static int lua_handler(request_rec *r) function is located in httpd-2.4.43/modules/lua/mod_lua.c
- static void ap_proxy_http_register_hook(apr_pool_t *p) is located in httpd-2.4.43/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_wstunnel.c

When I compile, I get this error:
mod_proxy_wstunnel.c:19:10: fatal error: ../../mod_lua.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include "../../mod_lua.h"

**Any help or idea is welcome.
Thank you at advance.**